# Permisson denied error while deleting a temporary files using php unlink function

Tags: php

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($tempFilesPath) as $fileData) 
{ 
   $fileName            = $fileData->getFileName();
   $fullFilePath        = $tempFilesPath.$fileName;
   $fileExtension       =  $fileData->getExtension();
  { 
    switch($fileExtension)
     case 'csv':unlink($fullFilePath); break;
     case 'pdf' :unlink($fullFilePath); break;
     case 'html': unlink($fullFilePath); break;
 }
}
 /* Delete the files from temp directory , Permission denied error is coming */
```

Comment: please add the code that is causing the permission error. Also are you administrating the server? it could be that `unlink` is not an allowed function, or the directory you are trying to unlink from a directory you don't permissions to access files from

Comment: do you want to unlink from other domains with same user ?
what is your php ? cli or cgi its important ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it the webserver temp or system temp?

Try setting permission to the file using chown()
chown($fullFilePath,465); //Insert an Invalid UserId to set to Nobody Owner; for instance 465
//Then try unlink'ing the file

If it doesnot work try doing
chmod($fullFilePath, 0666)

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594898/permission-denied-php-unlink)