# PHP unlink() Permission Denied

Tags: php, permission-denied

I am trying to unlink a file but keep getting a permission denied error.

The folder I am attempting to modify within has permissions `0775`

I am trying to unlink file.pdf from unlink.php... The folder structure is as follows:

```
root / folder1(PasswordProtected) / unlink.php
root / folder2 / file.pdf
```

I have tried the following from unlink.php (but to no avail):

```
if(file_exists("../folder2/file.pdf"))
{
    chmod("../folder2/file.pdf",0777);
    unlink("../folder2/file.pdf");
}
```

I think my question is similar to [permission denied - php unlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594898/permission-denied-php-unlink) but honestly I just don't understand what I have to do...

**Additional:** If I change `folder2` to 0777 in cPanel then I have no issues, but I don't want the public making changes to the file.. (is this correct? or have I misunderstood what 0777 does?)

Thanks for any help.!

Comment: what is the ownership of folder2?  the files?

Comment: With hosting or on your own server? If its hosted, contact the hosting company.

Comment: Double check if path to file is correct from script perspective.

Comment: @nomistic owner is user.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz the file path is correct because I am able to upload files to the directory, I just can't remove files / unlink.?

Comment: you might try setting it to the server (e.g. apache)

Comment: @nomistic So just to clarify, there doesn't seem to be anything out of place with my syntax? Sorry but I'm not really sure what you mean in your last comment....

Comment: I meant `chown` the directory to the server and see if that works

Comment: [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) to see what user PHP is running as.  I'm assuming it is running under mod_php as apache or nobody.

Comment: @Devon it returns jackjill...

Comment: I assume jackjill is the same user who owns this file then?  For deleting a file, you need to have write access to the directory.  So check your access level on folder2.

Comment: @Devon .. oh sorry, yes it is.. .. So just to clarify, I am able to upload from the php script, but I can't unlink..? Also, plz see updated question.

Comment: I would assume you'd need the same permission to write a file to folder2 as you would to unlink.  If you need `0777` permissions, then I'm assuming jackjill doesn't own folder2.

Comment: @Devon I can write with 0775 perms i agree with your assumption, which is why i'm so confused at why this isn't working... P.s. I really appreciate the considerable effort you're putting in to assist me..... print_r(posix_getpwuid(fileowner("../folder2"))); returns  [name] => jackjill print_r(posix_getpwuid(fileowner("../folder1"))); returns  [name] => jackjill

Comment: That is strange.  I'm at a loss then without more information or looking deeper into it first hand.

Comment: @developerwjk We are going to contact the hosting company. - Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side issue. Full description of issue was not provided by hosting company. Now resolved.