# unlink() with scandir() . php error Permission denied (document/.) and (document/..)

Tags: php, unlink, scandir

In the folder "`scanner ()`" whether screening, after "`unlink ()`" and I do unenroll ,If deleting the files in the folder, but I am getting permission denied error :

```
Warning: unlink(path/.): Permission denied in unlink.php on line

Warning: unlink(path/..): Permission denied in unlink.php on line
```

my `unlink` php code :

```
$Pscan = scandir("img/movieData/$m_folder/poster/");
     foreach($Pscan as $Pscan_name){
         unlink("img/movieData/$m_folder/poster/$Pscan_name");    
     }
```

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594898/permission-denied-php-unlink

Comment: I tried it but I could not

Comment: your php instance has not the needed rights to delete the files, if you using linux based system, check the rights for the file and who is the owner and und what user the php instance runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed :

```
$Pscan = scandir("img/movieData/$m_folder/poster/");
         foreach($Pscan as $Pscan_name){
             // fixed
             if($Pscan_name == '.' || $Pscan_name == '..'){
                   continue;
             }else{
                   unlink("img/movieData/$m_folder/poster/$Pscan_name");
             }   
         }
```